# How to plot a 2D RGB colormap from array?

Tags: python, colors, grid, colormap

I am trying to plot a 2D colormap.
I would imagine something like this:

```
grid = np.ndarray([2,2])
grid[0,0] = [35,74,3]
grid[0,1] = [146,252,7]
grid[1,0] = [215,84,14]
grid[1,1] = [16,62,8]

plotter.map(grid)
```

What library supports this?

Comment: you can use [matplotlibs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) `imshow()`. It supports directly plotting numpy arrays and colormaps can be specified. Also many tutorials exist online on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import random
import numpy as np

steps = 100

grid = np.ndarray([steps,steps,3])

for step_search_depth in range(steps):
    for step_simulated_games_per_state in range(steps):
        colour = random.randint(0,200)
        grid[step_search_depth, step_simulated_games_per_state] = (colour,colour,colour)

Image.fromarray(grid, 'RGB').show()
```